# xpages Unexpected runtime error after partial refreshing a panel

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected runtime error

The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
```

after a partial refresh from an `inputText`":

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText5" value="#{docInfoPiata.Companie}">
         <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Info">
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

Strangely, I use in many other xpages elements this refresh, and it works without any problems.

Comment: Is there any more information in the XPages-related logs on the server or on the Network tab in the browser? There's very little in that error message to suggest a cause.

Comment: I can not even click the Stack trace.

Comment: try removing piece by piece until it works

Comment: Is this on the default error page or a custom error page? Custom error pages cannot use XPages functionality, e.g. a Section control, so you'll need to use standard HTML to display/hide or show the section expanded. I've previously blogged about that http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-error-pages-partial-refresh-and-javascript/ (blog currently down). The Network tab in Firebug or the error files on the server will give full information.

Comment: It is on the default error page... I've never seen this kind of error before. Hope to get it fixed. I use this approach, many times: I have a value picker selecting some values and put them inside an input box. This inputbox onchange event fires a partial refresh to a panel.

Comment: Check your XPages log file using XPages Log File Reader and let us know what the detailed error message is.

Comment: Your partial refresh refreshes an element with server id of 'Info'. What does that element look like?

Comment: It is a panel, as the question describes.